Getting source code of RMarkdown script from HTML output
Is there a way to inspect the source code of an output HTML document that was created from an RMarkdown document?  I knit an RMarkdown document to HTML and I'm trying to find the source code of the RMarkdown document.  Can I do this somehow, using the output HTML document?

What exactly do you mean? That you have an HTML document where e.g. in some hidden tag the content of the corresponding .Rmd is written, such that one can inspect the document and see these contents somewhere?

yes, that's exactly what I mean, is that possible?

What you need is the option code_download. If you include this, e.g. as described in the linked R Markdown Cookbook:

output:
  html_document:
    code_download: true


, then you get a button inside the HTML file which can be used for downloading the .Rmd source code.

If you want to have the button invisible, you could use
```{js, echo=FALSE}
document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0].style.display = 'none'
```

inside the .Rmd and later set the display to 'inline-block' if you want to make it visible, e.g. in the browser.

Thought this was a default, but...
From inside your .Rmd file:
Options (little gear icon) > Output Options...(last choice) > Advanced > 'Create a standalone HTML document'
If you mean 'source code' as in.. what's handling the pandoc execution...
rmarkdown::render

